# No FileSystem for scheme: abfss - running pyspark standalone

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-lake

Trying to read csv file stored in Azure Datalake Gen2 using standalone spark but getting `java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: abfss`

Installed pyspark using: `pip install pyspark==3.0.3` and running it using following command, containing required deps:

`pyspark --packages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.0.3,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure-datalake:3.0.3"`

I found another answer here suggesting using `Spark 3.2+` with `org.apache.spark:hadoop-cloud_2.12` but it didn't work either, still getting the same exception, complete stack trace is pasted below:

```
>>> spark.read.csv("abfss://raw@teststorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/members.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dev/binaries/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 737, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dev/binaries/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/Users/dev/binaries/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/dev/binaries/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.csv.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: abfss
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:795)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to use a version of hadoop-* JARs built in the last five years. ABFS support came in Hadoop 3.2.0 with [HADOOP-15407. Support Windows Azure Storage - Blob file system in Hadoop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15407) and has not been backported for the reason "if people can't be bothered to upgrade, why should we bother to backport?". Do make sure all versions of the hadoop libraries are the same unless you want to see different stack traces. When integrating with Spark, you can package these versions in your app, and look for a config mentioning "user classpath first".
2. You need to define an environment variable `SPARK_CONF_DIR` to a folder and add a `core-site.xml` file in that path, which defines Hadoop Azure specifics like the ABFS account details

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html

Make note of `fs.azure.always.use.https` config option for using abfss.

Also, your error says you're using Spark 3.1.2, so your package versions need to match that